# spring convert buffered image into response entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have BufferedImage in my spring boot application. Now I want to send that file to user. How can I do that ?

**I'm looking for method to convert BufferedImage into ResponseEntity.**

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write-java.awt.image.RenderedImage-java.lang.String-java.io.OutputStream-, https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-async-output-stream

Answer (score 2):

you can also convert it to  `byte[]` using `javax.imageio.ImageIO`

```
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage , "png", byteArrayOutputStream);

byte[] imageInByte = baos.toByteArray();
```

then you controller is simplified:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/path", method = GET)
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getResource() {

   return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "filename=\"image.png"\")
            .contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG)
            .body(imageInByte);
```